# GIT rebase requires to recommit changes

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-rebase

Before anything else, I'm just new to git branching. I wasn't aware that every feature branch should be branched out from `master` and only use the pre-requisite feature branch with such relation to the next feature branch.

I have three branches. `master`, `feature-1` and `feature-2` all pushed the a Bitbucket repository (with issue tracking enabled). The thing is commits `M4` and `M5` are critical commits that all branches should rebase it before committing a merge (task of `git rebase`)

```
M1 -- M2 -- M3 -- M4 -- M5   [master]
  \        /
   A1 --- A2                 [feature-1]
           \
            B1 -- B2 -- B3   [feature-2]
```

The development for `feature-2` is done and is now needed to be merged to master. Here's the precedence of tasks I've done for `feature-2` to rebase `M4` and `M5` commits to `feature-2`.

1. `git push` - development of `feature-2`
2. `git checkout feature-2`
3. `git rebase master`
4. Resolve conflicts
5. `git pull`

After doing those steps I've noticed after executing `git status`. I have to push again all the commits (`feature-2`, `M4`, `M5` and conflict commits). Well all I have to do is just do `git push` and initiate the pull request and I'm done, right? But that would add another git commit comments to the issue tracker.

Is there a way to rebase `feature-2` to `master` without the need to push again the commits of `feature-2`, `M4` and `M5` and the `git log` should contain conflict commits.

**Update**

- Change the question details for better clarrification

Comment: Could you clarify your use of the term *GIT-flow*? Are you actually following [this workflow](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/)? Also, why would you rebase a branch (`feature-2`) that has already been pushed to a public remote repository?

Comment: Yes. But it should be *GIT branching* not *GIT-Flow*

Comment: You can always edit your question for clarification.

Comment: What do you mean by "it requires me to re-commit my changes again"? Why does it require you to do that? And which changes?

Comment: @Zeeker. I was worried since after pulling it says on `git status` that I have `N` commits ahead (which was the entire `feature-2`). Thus could trigger another set of git-commit comments on the concern issues.

Comment: Just create a new local branch from feature-2 and rebase that wrt master.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since you have pushed both feature branches already, you shouldn’t rebase at all. Rebasing already published branches is strongly discouraged since it breaks other developer’s repositories. The reason for that is that a rebase is just a *complete rewrite* of the commits. The commits you are rebasing are recreated, with changed contents, and—most importantly—with different hashes. This causes the new commits to be incompatible to the old ones, so whoever had the old ones ends up being in conflict with the new ones which replace them.

The proper solution for this is to simply merge the changes. While this might not end up looking so pretty, it is a non-destructive action in which no existing commits are changed. All that happens is that commit are *added* which will result in no problems when pushing or pulling.

That being said, you *can* rebase and still publish the changed branches. But to do so, you will need to force-push the branches and other developers pulling those changes will need to reset their branches to the new versions.

---

To incorperate some of my comments below into the answer: It’s important to understand that in Git, branches are just pointers to commits. The whole history—without branches—is a large acyclic graph where commits just point to their parent commits. So to take your example from the question, this is the history, without any branch pointers:

```
A -- B -- C -- D -- E
 \       /
  F --- G
         \
          H -- I -- J
```

Each letter represents a commit and all commits one is connected to *to the left* are its parent. So for example `F`’s parent is `A`, and `C` is a merge commit with the parents `B` and `G`.

Now, if we add branches to that visualization, then we just add pointers that point to some commits. It’s really nothing else (a branch is literally just a file that contains the hash of a commit):

```
                  master
                    ↓
A -- B -- C -- D -- E
 \       /
  F --- G  ← feature-1
         \
          H -- I -- J
                    ↑
                feature-2
```

Now, imagine we make a commit to the `feature-2` branch. We add that commit to the tree …

```
         \
          H -- I -- J -- K
                    ↑
                feature-2
```

… and then we move the branch pointer one forward:

```
         \
          H -- I -- J -- K
                         ↑
                     feature-2
```

Now, to understand what happens during a push, we need to remember that remote branches are also just branches, and as such just another set of pointers. So it actually looks like this:

```
         \
          H -- I -- J ----------- K
                    ↑             ↑
           origin/feature-2    feature-2
```

I think you can imagine what happens during a push now: We tell the remote repository to update its branch pointer so it points to `K`. But the server only has `J`, so we need to give the server everything to construct the tree accessible by `K` (so any other commits in between, and all the actual contents of those commits). But of course we don’t need to physically push `J`, or `H`, or even `A` (although those are all *technically* on the `feature-2` branch since you can *reach* them); Git is smart enough to figure out which objects are actually missing (you can see Git calculating that when you start a push).

So once we transferred the missing objects to the remote repository, we then tell the remote repository to update its `feature-1` pointer, so it will also point at `K`. And if that succeeded, we also update our remote branch (`origin/feature-2`) to point to it too (just to get in sync).

Now, the situation is really the same with merges. Imagine that we merged `master` into `feature-2` (using `git merge master` while on `feature-2`):

```
                  master
                    ↓
A -- B -- C -- D -- E -----
 \       /                 \
  F --- G  ← feature-1      \
         \                   \
          H -- I -- J -- K -- L
                              ↑
                          feature-2
```

Now, if we want to push `feature-2`, we again need to give the remote repository all the objects it doesn’t have. And since we are on a merge commit now, we need to check *all* parents: So if the server didn’t have `K` we would need to push `K`; But also, if it doesn’t have `E`, we would have to push `E`. And of course we need to follow those parents again to make sure that all objects exist on the remote. And once that’s done, we just tell the remote again to update the branch pointer.

So to sum this up: A branch *contains* all commits that are somehow accessible by navigating the parents of its commits in the acyclic tree. But even if that means that branches are usually very “big” (in length of history), Git will only transfer those objects to the remote repository that it doesn’t have. So although a merge can add many more commits to a branch, those doesn’t necessarily have to be transferred if the remote already knows about them from another branch.

---

And finally, some last words on rebasing: Above we did `git merge master` to merge the `master` branch into `feature-2`. If we did `git rebase master` instead, the full tree would look like this now:

```
                  master               feature-2
                    ↓                      ↓
A -- B -- C -- D -- E -- H' -- I' -- J' -- K'
 \       /
  F --- G  ← feature-1
         \
          H -- I -- J -- K
                         ↑
                  origin/feature-2
```

As you can see, there are new commits `H'`, `I'`, `J'` and `K'`. These are the rewritten commits so that they start at `E` (where `master` pointed to at the time of the rebase) instead of `G`. Since we rebased, there is no merge commit `L`. And as made clear above, *the original commits still exist*. It’s just that there is no pointer left that points to them; so they are “lost” and will eventually be garbage collected.

So what is the problem when pushing now? The remote branch still points to the original `K`, but we want it to point to `K'` now. So we start giving the remote repository all the objects it needs, just like before. But when we tell it to set update the branch pointer, it will refuse to do that. The reason for that is that by setting the pointer to `K'` it would have to “go back in the history” and ignore the existence of commits `H` to `K`. It doesn’t know that we have rebased those and there is also no link between the rewritten ones and the original ones. So just to prevent accidental data loss, the remote will refuse to update the branch pointer.

Now, you can *force push* the branch. This will tell the remote repository to update the branch pointer even though doing so would throw those original commits away. So you do that, and the situation will look like this:

```
                                   origin/feature-2
                  master               feature-2
                    ↓                      ↓
A -- B -- C -- D -- E -- H' -- I' -- J' -- K'
 \       /
  F --- G  ← feature-1
```

So far, everything is well: You decided to rebase the branch, and you told the remote repository to accept that without questioning it. But now imagine I wanted to *pull* that; and my branch is still pointing to `I`. So running pull does the same as a push in reverse: The remote gives me all the objects necessary to complete the history and then it tells me where to set the branch pointer. And at that point, my local Git refuses to do so for the same reason the remote repository did that before.

With the push before, we had the knowledge that we wanted to replace the original commits; but with a pull we don’t have that, so we are now required to investigate, or ask around, whether we should just replace our local branch, or if there’s actually some fault on the remote. And the situation gets even worse if we did some work on our own locally which we would want to merge now.

And these problems happen to everyone that fetched those original commits once. In general, you want to avoid this mess completely, so the rule is to never rebase something that you have already published. You can rebase as long as nobody else ever got those original commits, but as soon as that’s no longer the case, it will be a mess for everyone involved. So a merge is definitely preferred.

Comment: By doing force-push, could add another commit comment to affected issues?

Comment: If you force-push, whatever you are pushing will be overwritten on the server, no question asked. So when there were other commits, they are simply gone. That’s also why you should avoid it.

Comment: Why should it be avoided since those contents the commits where the same from the feature branch with just the addition of the merge conflicts (if any)?

Comment: As I explained in my answer, rebasing the commits creates new incompatible objects, so you’re breaking the repository of everyone who has fetched those original objects before.

Comment: I see. Well have to result to use `git merge` instead. Oh. I just noticed that after doing `git merge master` on `feature-2`, it requires me to push again `M4` and `M5` on `feature-2`. Would there be a way to avoid those commits since it was already pushed to `master`?

Comment: Since branches are just *pointers* to single commits, you are not really physically transferring those commits. But since they are now part of the merged feature-2, they are included in the push.

Comment: So if I get this currently, whenever one branch (`master`) is ahead of the to be merged branch (`feature-2`), I need to push again the commits of that branch (`feature-2`)? But why is it the behaviour when I do a merge on `master` from `feature-2` it only requires me to push the merge? If so, it is possible also to be done vice versa (`feature-2` will be merged with `master` [with or without commits])?

Comment: If you merge `master` into your feature branch, then technically all the commits that were on master but weren’t on the feature branch are *new* to the branch and as such need to be pushed. This is true for any merge situation. However, since you have published both branches already, those “new” commits are already known to the server and Git will respect that and actually only transfer the new objects.

Comment: So basically, there's no other way to avoid duplicating the commit comment on the issue tracker whenever you have to merge?

Comment: It's not duplicated. When you merge, then that merge commit just *points* to the existing commit. There is no physical copy, it's just a pointer that will be set. It's just when you look at the history of a branch, all its parent commits (the commits the branch's head commits points to, and those parents, and their parents, etc.) are shown. But since Git is a acyclic directed graph, individual commits may be used more than once, so they can appear multiple times depending on how you render the history.

Comment: @KaidoShugo I updated my answer with some additional details… I probably went *a bit* off-topic but I hope it still helps to understand what’s going on!

Comment: Thanks for the informative explanation when to use rebase or merge. Anyways, I can already accept this answer though I still have problems with duplicate comment commits pertaining to the issue (via Bitbucket or GitHub) though this happens when merging from master to a feature branch not on pull request.

Comment: Excellent post poke. I'm looking for a bit of clarification.
Let's say I make a few commits on a new branch and I've pushed my updated branch to origin; nobody else will have done work on this branch; but they may have fetched it.  I would like to delete one of these commits completely (because it deleted a file that I don't want removed from others machines).  It sounds to me like the new commits that others might have fetched will become 'lost' both on origin, and other clones; and there should be no issue.  Is this correct?

Comment: @PatrickCummins Others having fetched it is exactly the problem, they already know the old version, so if you replace the branch by something else, their copy is incompatible. For branches where you are the sole author and which will not be the base for other's work, this won't be such a big problem. A subsequent fetch will just update the remote tracking branch. So you _can_ rebase such branches but you should still avoid it. It all comes down to properly communicating this in the team. If you make clear what branches are used in what way, you will usually be fine.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand, the rules of your codebase (team) demand you to rebase your feature branch against the `master`. You could do that by saying `git rebase --onto master A2 feature-2` which would mean "take commits of the feature-2 starting with A2 exclusive and place them on top of the master". You could then push your changes directly to `master` and drop or keep the `feature-2` branch intact, again depending on the workflow conventions.

If on the other hand, the rebase is not demanded - you could well do a simple merge of the `feature-2` into `master`, pushing the change to the `master`, as @poke recommends.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to rebase `feature-2` to `master` without the need to push again the commits of `feature-2`

Not really, considering a rebase will replay the commits of feature-2 on top of master, given you this:

```
M1 -- M2 -- M3 -- M4 -- M5   [master]
  \        /              \
   A1 --- A2 [feature-1]   A1' --- A2'
                                     \
                                      B1' -- B2' -- B3'   [feature-2]
```

As the `'` sign indicates, all the commits have changed (their SHA1 is different).

Since `A1` and `A2` were already merged into `master`, a better rebase would be

```
git rebase --onto master A2 feature-2
```

That would get:

```
M1 -- M2 -- M3 -- M4 -- M5   [master]
  \        /              \
   A1 --- A2 [feature-1]   B1' -- B2' -- B3'   [feature-2]
```

You should `git push --force` that newly revised `feature-2` branch in order to update your pull request.

A forced push should update a pull request in Bitbucket since it supports such a push since Q4 2012 ([issue 4913](https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issue/4913/pull-requests-cant-handle-push-force-bb)).
A forced push won't have any other adverse effects, considering you are pushing a branch to *your* fork where, presumably, you are the only one to push updates.
Since the pull request will automatically updates itself with the new history of `feature-2`, that won't compromise said pull-request.

Comment: no, you generally shouldn't `push --force`. That's kind of *bad thing* and should generally be avoided, and if advised, should really be warned about. Of course, if we're talking about private fork only shown to user, push --force might be ok, but it really should have a disclaimer mentioned anyway.

Comment: @eis in term of pull request, a forced push is standard practice. I have edited the answer to explain why.

Comment: @VonC. by doing so, will create another commit comment on the affected issue(s) relating to `feature-2`?

Comment: @KaidoShugo no, for a pull request, it will replace the old history with the new one.