# Git - Merging two commits which are not in serial sequence - Commits pushed to remote repo already

Tags: git, merge, commit, rebase

I have read about merging two commits that are in a sequence, but how can i merge two commits which are not immediate to each other.

Like, my current commit with an old commit

Commits are in seq

```
er34rwe commit4
rtt45y5 commit3
iwe8j89 commit2
4E89E8J commit1
```

now, i would need to merge commit4 with commit2 and possibly place the result in the position of commit2. so that the result is

```
rtt45y5 commit3
iwe8j89 commit2_4 <-- new one
4E89E8J commit1
```

**Is there a way to do this if the commits are already pushed to the remote repository? and the remote repository to have the new history. i.e. both the commits to show as one.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use interactive rebase for this. Assuming that `er34rwe` is the earliest commit, do this:

```
git rebase -i er34rwe
```

This will launch your editor with a view like this:

```
pick er34rwe commit4
pick rtt45y5 commit3
pick iwe8j89 commit2
pick 4E89E8J commit1
```

You can then first change the order of those commits by simply moving the lines around:

```
pick rtt45y5 commit3
pick er34rwe commit4
pick iwe8j89 commit2
pick 4E89E8J commit1
```

And then you can also change the `pick` to another mode (they are explained at the bottom of the editor) to change them. In your case, you want to change the `commit2` to `squash` to meld it into the previous one (`commit4` – the file is read from top/oldest to bottom/newest commit):

```
pick rtt45y5 commit3
pick er34rwe commit4
squash iwe8j89 commit2
pick 4E89E8J commit1
```

Then save and exit the editor to start the process. Git will then rebase all the commits and prompt you to manually merge the commit message for those two commits you are combining.

Comment: I was aware about this method, but i was wondering if this it was possible to do if those commits are already pushed to the remote repository. Sorry didn't mention in the question. edited now

Comment: Rebasing already published commits *is* possible but definitely not recommended. Any solution would involve changing already published commits which will break any other contributor or user of your repository. So just don’t do it and live with it.

Comment: ..hmm, is there a way to delete a commit in the remote repository? Like if you have sqashed and pushed a commit. It has a duplicate, the one  initially committed, which does not have the new changes.

Comment: Any action that removes existing commits (rebasing is essentially a rewrite of commits that results in *new* commits replacing the old ones) is equally bad. You can use a forced push to just replace whatever the server has, but that has serious implications to others, and you really should avoid it. Check [this answer of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27856364/git-rebase-requires-to-recommit-changes/28041114#28041114) for more information about how the push and rebase mechanism works and why rebasing breaks.