# what happens downstream when force pushing a git rebased history

Tags: git, git-rebase

Imagine that someone forces a rebased push and people downstream have been doing things, what would happen to them? Do they have to remerge all conflicts again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rebasing causes commits to be *recreated*, as new objects which are incompatible with the old ones. Since you replace the branch pointer, everyone that still has references to the old commit objects (i.e. everyone who fetched the repository before you rebased it) will have to manually resolve this by resetting their branches (local or remote branches) to those new commits. This is especially difficult if they actually have local changes. In that case, they will have to rebase too.

So in general, a force-push of rebased commits will likely break others’ repositories in a way that they need to manually fix it. So you should avoid rebasing *any* commit that has been published in the past.

If you are interested in what happens during a force-push, and how that affects merges and rebases, check out [my answer on another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28041114/216074) where I go into a lot more detail.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, they might lose history and downstream could be "dangeling" which is a bad thing. You could end up cherry-picking your work somehow back onto track.

So never do forced pushes onto master!

On the other hand, if your downstream has been rebased the same way, so that upstream and downstream can find a common ancestor, things should be fine. Conflicts may occur though. But don't try this with master! ;)